# inheritance missing definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a simple program to understand inheritance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public enum AnimalType
    {
        Dog = 0,
        Cat = 1
    }
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog dog = new Dog();

            dog.printAnimal();
        }
    }

    class Animal
    {
        public string AnimalName;
        public AnimalType AnimalType;

        public Animal()
        {
            SetAnimalName ("");
            SetAnimalType (AnimalType.Dog);
        }

        public Animal (string animalName, AnimalType animalType)
        {
            SetAnimalName (animalName);
            SetAnimalType (animalType);
        }

        public virtual void PrintAnimal ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal::PrintAnimal -> this function should not get called");
        }

        private void SetAnimalName (string animalName)
        {
            this.AnimalName = animalName;
        }

        private void SetAnimalType (AnimalType animalType)
        {
            this.AnimalType = animalType;
        }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public Dog ()
        {
            base.Animal("Doggy", AnimalType.Dog);
        }

        public override void PrintAnimal ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bark");
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public Cat()
        {
            base.Animal("Kitty", AnimalType.Cat);
        }

        public override void PrintAnimal()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meow");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> Error 1   'ConsoleApplication1.Dog' does not contain a definition for 'printAnimal' and no extension method 'printAnimal' accepting a first argument of type 'ConsoleApplication1.Dog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\hk\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    24  17  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 2'ConsoleApplication1.Animal does not contain a definition for Animal   C:\Users\hk\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    65  18  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 3   ConsoleApplication1.Animal does not contain a definition for 'Animal'   C:\Users\hk\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    78  18  ConsoleApplication1

I create a base class called animal; and dog and cat inherit animal.
shouldn't it dog and cat have all the animal definition by default since they inherit animal?

Comment: Uppercase/lowercase issue

Comment: `dog.printAnimal()` should be `dog.PrintAnimal()`

Comment: `public enum AnimalType` Why do you need to keep track of what type of animal it is? The type tells you. `if (myAnimalVariable is Dog) Console.WriteLine("Hello, this is dog.");` What if I want to declare my own animal. Now I'm boned (no pun intended) because I can't update your enum.

Comment: People who write "no pun intended" almost _always_ intended the pun :-)

Comment: @ta.speot.is: This topic is of course controversial. But in college, we learned that `instanceof` operators are a warning of bad design. You should try to use dynamic binding instead.

Comment: @CommuSoft That's not my point. My point is the enum is redundant, not that you should use `is`. If you need to treat derived classes differently from their base classes you've broken LSP.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That's true, but the proposed resolution is almost as bad since you write `if`-statements and thus reduce the number of possible Animals to a finite number (the number of `if`-statements). If later someone not familiar with the code adds another animal, things might go wrong.

Comment: @CommuSoft What resolution? I just showed the type can give you the information, not that you should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use consistent naming. Here you define `PrintAnimal` in uppercase, but calls it in lowercase.

```
class Dog : Animal {

    public Dog () {
        base.Animal("Doggy", AnimalType.Dog);
    }

    public override void PrintAnimal () {
        Console.WriteLine("Bark");
    }

}
```

next, a `base` construction call in C# is done like:

```
public class Dog {

    public Dog () : base("Doggy", AnimalType.Dog) {
    }

}
```

and same for `Cat`.

Finally, I would advice you to use `abstract` for a method you don't define:

```
abstract class Animal {

    //...

    public abstract void PrintAnimal ();

}
```

as a result, the compiler will check if you did an `override` on that method reducing inconsistencies (e.g. forgetting to override, override another method with almost the same name, etc.).

An `abstract class` prevents a programmer from "constructing an Animal" this is reasonable since there exist no `Animal`s, only `Cat`s and `Dog`s who are grouped as animals.

Answer (score 2):

`printAnimal` is **not** the same as `PrintAnimal`. Fix the capitalisation of your function name.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    dog.PrintAnimal();    // NOT printAnimal !!
}
```